# How to disable img <a href> link only on mobile, allow in web?

Tags: jquery, html

Using jQuery or another method, I want to disable all  links on mobile device and tablets, but still allow the links to work on web/desktop.
The code I have:

```
<div class="large-12 columns photos">
  <div><a href="larger_image1.jpg"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div><a href="larger_image2.jpg"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div><a href="larger_image3.jpg"><img src="image3.jpg" /></a></div>
</div>
```

Strategy: sniff user device, then if mobile, set the link to "javascript:void(0)" or similar.

I hope this is a good question this time. I did some searches both here and on Google, but couldn't solve.

Thanks!
Brian

Comment: what effort have you made to sniff?

Comment: Can we just hide the link if it's a mobile device?

Comment: If on mobile, set <a> display:none, then the <img> inside of that will be invisible too. I still want the <img> inside the link to show on mobile/table. Just want to disable the link.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean "disable" as in changing it's url, e.g. `index.html` into `#`, then we can do something like this:

```
// Detect different screens.
$(window).resize(function()
{
    // Detect the current screen width.
    var width = $(window).width();
    // Determine what you define a as a mobile screen size.
    var mobileScreen = 900;
    // Check whether the condition applies.
    if(width <= mobileScreen)
    {
        // Change every href attribute of every a element with #
        $('a').attr('href', '#');
        // You can also hide them, if you want, with
        // $('a').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        // Do nothing otherwise, 
        // or change the href attribute back to an actual url, using ids.
    }
}).resize(); // Trigger the re-size event on page load.
```

Comment: I don't like this solution so much but I did not find anything that was working well so thanks for the tip!

Comment: Your function( needs a )

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.photos a').click(function(event){
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Very simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLjLdbfz/) for understanding. Try it on mobile, tablet and desktop to see if it works as you've planned.

Comment: What else can it be? I'm also pretty sure, that there are tablets with more than 900px width screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
This should get the work done:

<script type="text/javascript">
// get window width
var width = $(window).width();
// check if window width is smaller then 1024px (mobile or tablet
if(width < 1024) {
    // if yes then ...
    $("large-12.columns.photos a").click(function(e) {
        // this should prevent the clicking functionality
        e.preventDefault();
        // just to add some fun here
        alert('you are on mobile ... clicking doesnt work here');       
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: i did it on click event to show you the idea.

you can use on load or resize (you should use both of both to get the best situation and not leave bugs) as you desire.